# How to disable Saiku cache for all queries?

Tags: caching, crosstab, mondrian, saiku

I'm using Saiku to make crosstabs on a production software, which has new data all day long.

Everytime we need to click the "clear cache" button before opening or making a new query, it's really disturbing for our users.

I tried to look into mondrian.properties but there is a lot of cache options, and I can't find any documentation on which one to disable.

Did someone do that and can help me ?

Thanks,
Dev.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend disabling the cache unless you really need to as it causes a bunch of performance issues for your users.

But if you really want to, look in mondrian.properies and there is

```
#mondrian.rolap.star.disableCaching=false
```

which you can enable and set to true.